# Multiple Start/Stop VMs during off-hours solutions for a single Automation Account in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-automation

I'm trying to separate VMs inside a Resource Group and have two groups of VMs that each will have a different Start/Stop VMs during off-hours solution using the Resource Group's Automation Account.

When I tried creating a new Start/Stop VMs during off-hours solution while one already exists I'm getting the following error:

`Resource plan can not be changed for Resource id: '/subscriptions/myID/resourceGroups/xxx-start-stop-vms-test/providers/Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions/Start-Stop-VM[xxx-START-STOP-TEST-WORKSPACE]' (Code: CannotUpdatePlan)`

That error says basically that I'm trying to change an already existing solution which I'm not and what I understood from that is that I'm unable to create a new Start/Stop VMs during off-hours solution because there already is one.
I tried looking online for a solution for this but I couldn't find anything.
At this point I'm not even sure it's possible so I'm asking here; can you make two or more Start/Stop VMs during off-hours solutions on a single Automation Account?

Comment: you probably can if you give them different names?

Comment: There isn't really a name field when creating the solution.